# Ruby. How to write a loop of 1% percentage profit for one year on a 1000$ investment

Tags: ruby, loops, methods, iterator, percentage

I'd like to create a ruby program to calculate the 1% on my investment every day for one year.
For example, if I invest 1000$ and get a profit of 1% at the end of the day will be 1010.0$ The second day I will invest 1010.0$ and I will get a 1% profit of 1020.1$ and so on.
I'd like to determine after 365 days what will be my initial investment.
I'm trying with a loop to print every single returning value but as you see I'm still a superrookie.
Thanks. Sam

I made it alone! Thanks for all of your answers!

```
money = 1000
days = 0
perc = 0.01

while days < 366
  puts days
  puts money
  days += 1
  money = money * perc + money
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`BigDecimal`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html) instead of `Float` when dealing with monetary values:

```
require 'bigdecimal'

money      = BigDecimal('1000')
percentage = BigDecimal('0.01')
```

For the loop I'd use [`upto`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Integer.html#method-i-upto) which works very intuitively:

```
1.upto(365) do |day|
  money += (money * percentage).round(2)
  printf("%3d: %8.2f$\n", day, money)
end
```

- `money * percentage` calculates the day's profit, rounded to 2 digits via [`round`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html#method-i-round). You can adjust the [rounding mode](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html#method-c-mode) by passing a second argument.
- [`printf`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Kernel.html#method-i-printf) then outputs day and money using the given formatting:

  - `%3d` prints an integer with width 3
  - `%8.2f` prints a float with 2 fractional digits and a total width of 8

Output:

```
  1:  1010.00$
  2:  1020.10$
  3:  1030.30$
     ...
363: 37039.07$
364: 37409.46$
365: 37783.55$
```

Comment: The dollar-sign normally appears to the left of the specified amount.

Comment: @SagarPandya indeed, I just took the format from the OP's question.

Answer (score 2):

```
1000 * 1.01**365
#=> 37783.43433288728
```

You don't need to write a program for this; it's a one-line calculation.

But if you want to do it one day at a time and show the output of each day, how about:

```
money = 1000
(1..365).each do |day|
  money *= 1.01
  puts "After #{day} days: $#{money.round(2)}"
end
```

Comment: You probably have to round each single profit, not just the result. And you shouldn't use floats.

Comment: I don't work in finance, and this is not meant to be an enterprise-level solution... But yes, if you ever deal with numbers in important systems then you should *never* use floats, or you'll get subtle inaccuracies as pennies get rounded off!

Comment: Also, there might be laws prescribing when and how to round, if the money you are calculating with is not yours.

Answer (score 0):

The following is super simple but will get the job done. Basically you initialize a variable to 1000, we then loop 365 times. We have a block where all the math happens. It takes the value 1000 and multiplies it by 1.01 and overwrites the value of the intial investment. You can change the 365 to 2 or however many days you want. The puts print the value of the start. Just run this by putting it in a .rb file and running 'ruby file.rb'

```
start = 1000
365.times do
  start = start*1.01
  puts start
end

puts start
```

Comment: Naming-wise, it feels weird to reassign `start`. That is starting value, not a running counter. :)